# References, loading different copy of assembly at runtime

Tags: .net, reference, runtime

How can I reference a managed assembly in my project directory to be able to build my application, but then have the CLR load a different copy of that assembly (at a specified path) at run time?

Comment: You should clean your solution and rebuild. Your problem hard to indicate where the root cause.

Comment: Why you need something like that ?

Comment: I want to make sure that when my project runs on target machine, the DLL in C:\Program Files is used. I can only build my project if I make a local copy of that assembly on my development machine and reference it at design time

Comment: Is there no solution? Surely other .NET developers have needed to build against a DLL which will be present on target machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the assembly explicitly, but do it *before* it's loaded automatically e.g.

```
static class Program {
  static void Main() {
    ...
    // Loading assembly before it's implicitly loaded    
    String path = @"C:\Program Files\MyDlls\MyAssembly.dll"
    Assembly.LoadForm(path); 
    ...
    // First use of the loaded assembly 
    MyType v = new MyType();
```